# Ajax POST method to Django. Always results in "Not Ajax"

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

I have been trying to create an AJAX function which sends two JS variables, Score and Mistake, back to the Django backend and to update an extended user model with them.

To do this I started with an AJAX function which looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#test").submit(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         console.log("form submitted!");
            $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"/update/quiz/",
                 data: {
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN,
                        'score': score,
                        'mistake' : mistake
                        },
                 success: function(){
                     $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>") 
                 }
            });
            return false;
       });
});
```

Views.py

```
class Quiz(TemplateView):
    template_name='quiz.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
          message = "Yes, Ajax!"
        else:
          message = "Not Ajax!"
        return HttpResponse(message)
```

URLS.py

```
from django.urls import path

from home.views import HomepageName, Homepage, Quiz
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('quiz/', Quiz.as_view()),  
    path('update/quiz/', Quiz.post),
    path('<slug:slug>/', HomepageName.as_view()),
    path('', Homepage.as_view()),
]
```

And the template

```
<form method='POST' id ='test'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='submit' value='Test button'/>
        <div id = 'message'>Initial text</div>
</form>
```

I've already tried to move around the URL routing and add a new URL thinking that would work but when the Submit button is clicked then it always loads a new page and then on that page it shows "Not Ajax!"

I assume that it is doing the default HTML form action and not the AJAX since their is no output to the console either which I added to get some more information

Thanks for all your help. Please comment if I need to provide more information!

Comment: Is there a reason why you did not put `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in quotes?